# Json dependencies not automatically upgrading

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

Do I have to manually type in my dependencies in the json file or is here a way that it automatically updates the dependencies in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do `npm install`, it will update the `package.json` file if not there already. i think start from npm 5, `--save` is no longer require.

if you want to upgrade, there is a package call [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) which does the update check and upgrade if you want (by `ncu -a`)